# What's a better to say "made by me" on the bottom of my website?

Tags: editing, websites, copywriting

I'm a designer and I'm preparing my own portfolio website. Right on the bottom, I would like to mention that it is I (or me, just don't bite my head off :p ) who coded the website to highlight the fact that I also write code in addition to design. Most people say "**made by me**" which doesn't sound great to me. So, what's a better way of saying that without sounding too sophisticated and "grammarly inclined"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a more formal announcement such as...

*This site and all of the sites linked to from the "Gallery" page were hand-crafted by Ayadi Ghait.  They are under copyright and unauthorized duplication of the underlying source code for reuse is prohibited by the author.*

...Throwing in the copyright and usage information dilutes the boastfulness of the first statement, giving the entire paragraph a purpose, while still getting your primary point (that you personally created this site) across.

Comment: Waw man! Thanks. But That's a big paragraph. It's cool and I'm gonna use it somewhere for sure, but I needed just one sentence you know. Something friendly and cool.

Comment: "Handcrafted by Ayadi"

Comment: You're awesome man. Thanks a lot. Will use it

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the name you are promoting.  If the website is your business name, I'd sign with that down the bottom. If it is your first name I would use that. I wouldn't use your first name if you have a business name as that's not promoting yourself.

Definitely don't use 'handcrafted by me' though.

Comment: I went with "Handcrafted by Ghaith" as @HenryTaylor suggested. I feel it does embody the spirit of what that I'm trying to convey

Answer (score 0):

If you want to point out that you did both, why not just say "Designed and Coded by me"? (Although I also would use your official business name instead of "me".)

Comment: That would be a valid option as well. But my issue is with "by me". I could say: designed and coded by Ghaith, that would work for me